# How to check condition in splashscreen?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, splash-screen

I've implemented a splash screen. I want to check the condition if agree is empty go to the TermsAndCondition page else move HomePage. Below I've attached the code of splashscreen please find and check.

SplashScreen :

---

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newbharatbiz/Screens/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:newbharatbiz/Screens/TermsAndCondition.dart';
import 'package:newbharatbiz/Utils/MySharedPreferences.dart';


var agree;

void main() async {


  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  var initialRoute = '';

  MySharedPreferences.instance
      .getStringValue("agree")
      .then((value) => setState(() {
    agree = value;
  }));

  if (agree.isEmpty) {
    initialRoute = 'TermsAndCondition';
  }else{
    initialRoute = 'home';
  }

  runApp(MyApp(initialRoute: initialRoute));
}

setState(Null Function() param0) {
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String initialRoute;

  MyApp({required this.initialRoute});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: initialRoute,
        routes: {
          'TermsAndCondition': (context) => TermsAndCondition(),
          'home': (context) => HomePage(),
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: `MySharedPreferences.instance
      .getStringValue("agree")
      .then((value) => setState(() {
    agree = value;
  }));` use await .then take the route value other wise .most probabley else work eg:`var agree=await sharedpreference.getstring("agree");`

Answer (score 0):

if your shared preferences give the right data then change the initial route to your logical page.

```dart
initialRoute: agree == null || agree == ''? TermsAndCondition() : HomePage()
```